# Create a directory today and change to the new directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

My python code starts in a specific directory.
From this directory, I would like my script to automatically create a new directory by today's date and then change to that directory.

```
import datetime
todays_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d_%B_%Y')
os.chdir(r'/Users/me/Desktop/project/')
if not os.path.exists(todays_date):
    os.makedirs(todays_date)
```

The code above works well. Now, I just need to change to that directory without manually typing today's date. How can I achieve that task?

```
os.chdir(f'/Users/me/Desktop/project/._todays_date)
```

returns `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't close the string correctly. You forgot the ending '
2. You did not use f-strings correctly. To use a variable in a f-string, surround it with curly braces.

```py
os.chdir(f'/Users/me/Desktop/project/{todays_date}')
```

should work.